# Prove that for any bounded set there exist two monotone sequences such that their limits equal the sup and inf of the set.

Tags: real-analysis

Let S be a subset of the real numbers such that S is nonempty and bounded. Show that that there are exist two monotone sequences such that the limit of the first is equal to the supremum of S, and the limit of the second is equal to the infimum of S.

Comment: It would be easier to answer, if you write some peace of what you tried. I believe that the definitions of $\sup$ and $\inf$ will lead you to solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the approximation property of supremum and infimum. This is a standard fact.